# Добавить __proto__ в уже существующий объект "законными" методами

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект:

```
var ObjOne={
    foo:function(){return "smth";},
    bar:function(){return 1+1;}
};
```

и функция:

```
var smthFunc=function(){return 3+3;};
```

Мне нужно, чтоб я мог обратиться как к самой функции(`smthFunc()`), так и к свойствам ObjOne через неё(`smthFunc.foo()`).

При этом я не могу просто взять и присвоить функции свойства ObjOne(то-есть использовать Object.assign() и подобные решения).

Comment: ты лучше напиши что конкретно ты хочешь сделать? Пример с функцией - непонятен.

Comment: `A.smth = SmthObj;` тебе не нужен `__proto__`

Comment: Но мне нужен вызов напрямую... Так получается, что если у меня в SmthObj будет функция, то вызов будет через A.smth.func()

Comment: И при этом я не могу использовать примеси или Object.assign()

Comment: Еще раз: сформулируй задачу, которую ты хочешь решить. пока ничего непонятно.

Comment: Для добавления недостающей информации используй кнопку [edit] под вопросом

Comment: _При этом я не могу просто взять_ - почему не можешь?

Comment: Потому, что ObjOne постоянно обновляется.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67971/discussion-between-grundy-and-).